# Error in SSIS package after executing Mysql command

Tags: mysql, ssis

I want to write to a MySQL database from SSIS .I follow this tuto http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2009/01/07/writing-to-a-mysql-database-from-ssis.aspx
After executing this command

```
set @@global.sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,ANSI_QUOTES'
```

I got this error :

```
 Error: 0x0 at EndControlMonitoring: String or binary data would be truncated.
    Error: 0xC002F210 at EndControlMonitoring, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "EXEC FlowEndControlFlowMonitoring  ?, 0, ?,?
    " failed with the following error: "The statement has been terminated.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
    Task failed: EndControlMonitoring
    Warning: 0x80019002 at OnError: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
    Error: 0xC002F210 at Create AdjustEbsences Proc, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "USE ETL;
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS AdjustAbsences;
    ..." failed with the following error: "ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(a) Driver][mysqld-5.1.33]
```

Comment: It seems that you have an container on your package which has set Maximum number of errors to 2, and earlier in your package is happening two errors which break entire package. Include breakpoints into your package and in debug go step by step and realize what cause errors.

Comment: @veljasije The package works fine before executing the Command above